# I am trying to save this image in a folder but it is showing this error. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python, filesystems

This is my code

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

# Open an Image
FRAME_SIZE = (720,1280)
img = Image.new('RGB', FRAME_SIZE, color = 'black')

# Call draw Method to add 2D graphics in an image
I1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# Add Text to an image
I1.text((100, 100), "nice Car", fill=(255, 32, 0))

# Display edited image
img.show()

# Save the edited image
img.save("./new_folder/car2.png")
```

And this is error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Projects\devops-directive-hello-world\trial.py", line 19, in <module>
    img.save("./new_folder/car2.png")
  File "C:\Users\Pushpendra\Desktop\Drone\devops-directive-hello-world\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2317, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './new_folder/car2.png'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Most likely, there exists no folder called `new_folder` to save to.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the destination folder.

```
img.save("car2.png")
```

this will do the trick. At least you must choose an existing directory

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason for this error to occur is your Python directory is in C: so your relative path is referencing your Python directory only.

Work around in this case can be to use absolute path, like so : 'D/Python Projects/newfolder/'

Hopefully it solves your problem